# Indexing for group by + SUM query on mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing, group-by

I have a table with the following schema:

```
    CREATE TABLE `wordtrend` (
      `oid` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `monitorId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `nGram` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `nGramWord` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `negatives` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `neutrals` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `positives` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `total` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `trendCut` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`oid`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM 
      AUTO_INCREMENT=358539 
      DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8  COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Is it possible to create an index in order to run the following query efficiently?

```
SELECT nGram
     , nGramWord
     , SUM(total) AS sTotal
     , SUM(positives)
     , SUM(negatives)
     , SUM(neutrals) 
FROM WordTrend 
WHERE monitorId = 21751021 
  AND trendCut >= '2011-01-01 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY nGram
       , nGramWord 
ORDER BY sTotal DESC
```

We already tried the following:

```
KEY `RollupIndex` (`monitorId`,`trendCut`)
KEY `RollupIndex2` (`monitorId`,`nGram`,`trendCut`)
```

but we are getting "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort" on the extra column. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many rows are returned by the query? How much time does it take to run?

Comment: I'm curious what these 2 queries would show: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT nGram) FROM WordTrend` and `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT nGram, nGramWord) FROM WordTrend`

Comment: (Warning: They might be really slow without an index on `(nGram,nGramWord)`

Answer (score 0):

1. You sort by column without index so you get info  Using temporary; Using filesort
2. Using where; - you use where with or without index for searching in where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You use ordering - 'ORDER BY sTotal DESC', so index on `sTotal` field might help.

Comment: sTotal is the name of the SUM(total) column. I think you can't index sTotal, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try different combinations of KEY (`nGram`, `nGramWord`, `total`).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) to get usefull info about the performance, and optimize your query ?!